# Sign-up process shouldn't reveal that an email account is already in use

Tags: support, privacy, terms-of-service

I tried to create a new account using same email address I used to this account to just test this.

The following error appears.

> The email address you have used is already registered.

So any of my friend or any other person who knows my email address, easily find that whether I use the Stack Overflow or not. It is against privacy policy of Stack Overflow. Isn't it? Because I don't think that I have agreed to let others to know that I use Stack Overflow or not.

Comment: And your suggestion for replacement text that still conveys the same important message is...?

Comment: There is a long tradition in development in using messages as _"An unspecified error has occurred"_. Everybody loves those.

Comment: Well, the message isn't exactly letting users *identify* you on stackoverflow. If you are really that concerned about people figuring out that your email is used as one for the many SO accounts, you should probably have a 'site-sign-up' email -- separated from your personal one you hand out to people to contact you.

Comment: Okay, feature request: change the text to "We're not saying that this email address is already registered, but we can't accept it anyway because reasons".

Comment: I do not think there is much to do worry about this "issue", but a more agnostic _"You can't create an account with this e-mail"_ wouldn't be that bad or that hard. Yes, you can maybe guess that the account is in use, but you are not saying it directly, and it could be conflated with blocked/invalid e-mail addresses. Either that or go back to the _"An unspecified error has occurred"_ idea... :P

Comment: Email is just an other password and should be use as such https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/01/how-i-almost-lost-my-500000-twitter-username-jb-and-my-startup/

Comment: @Clive I am not suggesting this gets implemented but if the system could simply always say "Please check your email for a verification link" then the email sent to the user could convey whether or not they've already registered and provide supportive information such as "If you did not initiate this, then click here." and "You're already registered, need to reset your password?" or "Registration almost complete, please click this link to activate your account!"

Answer (score 4):

I think you're glossing over a very important detail:

**In order for SSO to work and for your account to be bound to an SSO service, you have to authenticate to that service.**

If your friends decided to try and register you on Stack Overflow through SSO, they have your account credentials and you have a *much* bigger problem than them knowing you have an account here to worry about.

Comment: Okay, my curiosity is overtaking now. But it is also possible to sign up without SSO isn't it? If you go to the signup page you have the option to just create an account with an email and password.

Answer (score -9):

Email is just an other password, You should not use the same email for different service. If creating multiple mail address is to much a burden you can use alias to add uniquness to an email like:

> MyAddress+ALIAS@foo.bar

This way people looking for your address will not have an error message.
And you will recieve a mail telling you to active the new account, as warning of an attempt.

You can simply change your mail address by the same with an alias.

The [plusaddressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Address_tags) is a method to add variation into a mail and is allowed by almost all email. It does not provide the same security of using one time email or multiple email address, but it has some advantage.

This does not provide the same level of security as multiple email address, and both can be use this way they both provide uniqness and spammer tracability.

Comment: I don't get the down vote, Plus addressing is somehow link to spam account but it's actually use for preventing them. By having a unic mail per service you know witch one sell your address.

Comment: Yeah, that'll set them right off. They'll never guess what the real address is.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier, I don't get you. Either you talk about the "familly" and they already had the password, or you talk about the website and you didn't understand that the alias is the real email. There is no fake email this is not a 10 minute mail. Or anything.

Comment: If you talk about someone else getting the email. Once again he has the real email are there is no fake. Will it be enought to brute force the password ? No really. In fact If the Alias is strong, The know email address in most of the case act like salt. A know one sure. Stil it does not make anything easier.

Comment: Just to prove my point, if I create an account "Please_elksdjhf@gmail.com" with "azerty1234" as password. Trying to guess the alias would be the same as trying to guess the password if you had the email. With a simplier api as accoutn creation will let you try as many time as you want. And login won't.

Comment: plusaddressing solve the "someone try my email and know that I use this service". As the alias will be need to log and to have the error on account creation. I will not adress the fact that credential was share. As I stated Login is just an other password.

Comment: Test comment foobar [\[meta-tag:feature-request\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/support)

Comment: Howdy @DragandDrop, how's the test going? everything cooking? :)

Comment: Fine always. Wanted to try to forge a comment tag link to point to an other tag for a pratical joke. Sorry for the notification.

Comment: It was a welcome activity on an otherwise completely uneventful MSO year.

Comment: Lets make this an anniversary. I will be back next year. You better have an eventfull So year this time.